# How can I call system level API with an existing executable?

Tags: c++, windows, security

I have an executable that is executed with admin privileges. One of the thing that it does is installing a Windows service, the code looks like this:

```
auto path = new wchar_t[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName( nullptr, path, MAX_PATH );
handles._service = CreateService( handles._scManager, _name.c_str(),
    _name.c_str(), READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS,
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, dwStartType, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
    path, nullptr, nullptr, dependencies.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
```

I have other system calls throughout the program.

Could this program be used by an external entity to execute system API calls?
If so, how would that person proceed and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Depends on what the service does, I figure?

Comment: The service calls the same executable with different parameters. Would it be possible to alter the program so that it installs another service, or calls other API function with different parameters?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I would think that to do something like what you're describing you would have to acquire a handle with OpenHandle with something like PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS. You shouldn't be able to do to an elevated process from a non-elevated process.

Comment: I do, not with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS though. The example code is really simplified, it was just for giving an example of the kind of API calls that I do.

Comment: If this hypothetical entity can run your program with admin privilege, he can run *any* program with admin privilege.  No need to mess around, he can just run `infectsystem.exe` directly.